# tar: ./03-Castaway\ on\ the\ Moon\ (Hae-jun\ Lee\ -\ 2009): Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to "copy" some files and folder from a external HD to my mac but before that I wanna copy them compressed
almost is ok except when the folders or files names has names with whitespaces.
I can't edit that names because the external HD is mounted for read only (in my Mac).

There is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
rar='.*\.(rar)$'
docx='.*\.(docx)$'
ITER=1
cd /Volumes/TDT/PC/Vídeos/peliculas/
for dir in ./*
do
  if [[ "$dir" =~ rar || "$dir" =~ docx ]]; then
    echo ""
  else
    echo "tar cz ${dir//\ /\ } | gzip > /Users/william/toUpload/movies/${ITER}.tar.gz"
    echo "..."
    tar cz "${dir//\ /\ }" | gzip > "/Users/william/toUpload/movies/${ITER}.tar.gz"
    ITER=$(expr $ITER + 1)
  fi
done
```

There is the error

```
tar: ./03-on\ the\ Moon: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

Of course the folder exist and have something inside and if I do `ls ./03-on\ the\ Moon` the folder show me their contain.

Comment: Why are you doing `${dir//\ /\ }` instead of just `$dir`?

Comment: And why are you piping to `gzip` if you're already using `z` with `tar`?

Comment: it is compressed twice then, or ignored?

Comment: @alexcs It's compressed twice, but the second layer of compression doesn't make it any smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I change `"$dir"` instead `${dir//\ /\ }` and it works!
    tar cz "$dir" | gzip > "/Users/william/toUpload/movies/${ITER}.tar.gz"

Thank you!